# How to set where an email is sent from?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have some email accounts configured. One of these emails (e.g. myemail@mail.com) gives access to some mailboxes (e.g. emaiolbox@mail.com).

[image]

If I choose "From" > "Other Email Address", then I can choose which account I want to use ("Send Using") and which email ("From").

I have a macro to reply to emails.

I'd like to set the "sent using" and "from" options.

```vb
Sub send_email()
    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem
    
    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Utils\Outlook_Templates\macro.oft")
    
    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.Subject = "RE: " + origEmail.Subject
    replyEmail.To = origEmail.Sender
    replyEmail.CC = origEmail.CC + ";" + replyEmail.CC
    replyEmail.Display
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at the `MailItem.Sender` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender

Comment: I am trying but still didn´t accomplish it. Help me please

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible options available in the Outlook object model:

1. The [SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1390)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) property allows setting an [Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.account) object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. The `SendUsingAccount` property can be used to specify the account that should be used to send the MailItem when the Send method is called. This property returns `Null` (`Nothing` in Visual Basic) if the account specified for the `MailItem` no longer exists.

```
      Sub SendUsingAccount()  
       Dim oAccount As Outlook.account  
       For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts  
        If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then  
         Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem  
         Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
         oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account"  
         oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com")  
         oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll  
         Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount  
         oMail.Send  
        End If 
       Next  
      End Sub
```

2. The [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1360)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) property allows setting a String indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. Note, in that case you need to be sure that you have sufficient permissions to send emails on behalf of another person.

Comment: I tried option number 1. And I press the macro but nothing happens. Any idea why?

Comment: What code do you have now? Did you try to debug the code? Any errors?

Comment: I opend my visual basic macros in Outlook and I just placed the code it was provided above (Sub SendUsingAccount). Just that. Than I changed the " oMail.Recipients.Add" line and changed it according to my email. After that I added a button in Outlook to call this. But when I press that button nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Do you get any errors under the debugger attached?